# Set date = tomorrow at a static time in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I need to set a DATE variable equal to tomorrow's date and I need to set the time to 12:00AM (static). I have the following code that works, but I think there's a cleaner way that I'm missing.

---

```
end_date:= to_date((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate+1))||'/'||
                   (EXTRACT(DAY FROM sysdate+1))||'/'||
                   (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate+1))||
                   ' 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI PM');
```

---

So that gets the job done, but is there an easier way for me to set the end_date variable?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
end_date:=trunc(sysdate+1);
```

?

Comment: I knew I was missing something easy, thanks for the response. I'll end up using 

`select trunc(sysdate +1) + 1/86400 from dual`

Comment: Note that `trunc(sysdate +1) + 1/86400` is 12.00.01AM and not 12.00AM as you said in the question.

Comment: I'd recommend using INTERVAL arithmetic for the sake of clarity; thus `end_date := trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day + interval '1' second`.  I find this much easier to interpret.  YMMV.